# how to highlight the rdl projects xml view in VS2003?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2003, rdl

i never worked with Reporting Services in the past and i notice that the XML view of the Rdl projects does not offer a syntax highlighting in VS2003 its all plain text

does someone knows how to enable this?

Thanks,

Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. That functionality did not exist back in 2002 when VS2003 was released.

I recommend you download one of the free Visual Studio Express editions. They have a nice XML editor, with syntax highlighting.

Comment: :( thank,s i already used 2008 but at work i am attached to 2003 :(

Comment: You can continue to use VS2003. You can simply use VS2008 Express as an XML editor. Both can be installed on the same system. At work, I have every VS version from VS6 onwards installed!